# Prevent user from opening issues

Tags: github, github-issues

I would like to stop a problem user from opening further issues and commenting. I own the repository. I see the block option, but it is not clear what it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did my own experiment, here is what I found:

- If you block a user, they will be prevented from commenting or opening issues on any repos that **you own**
- For any repos where you are a **collaborator**, they are unencumbered

Also I found this:

http://help.github.com/articles/blocking-a-user-from-your-personal-account